# Using a image path in a JSON object to dynamically render image in component

Tags: json, reactjs, nested, react-props, nested-object

I am running into an issue that seems to be "similar" to other issues dealing with a JSON object in React, though I can not seem how to translate these answers. I am creating a small game inside of React (not React Native). I am able to call my JSON object and pull text, though, when it comes to pulling an image path, it will not render. To get a basic idea of this game (that was in HTML/ JS) take a [look at this link for the overall functionality](https://zoosnatch.herokuapp.com/).

Here is the Issue, I have a dynamically rendering set of objects based on state in the parent Component (GameLogic.js). I am then passing state down to the great-great-grandchild elements where it will render a two photos. These photo paths are stored in a local JSON file (I can read strings from the characters.json file in a console.log at this level). Though it can read the path (via console.log), it is not rendering these images. I am how ever able to render these images as long as I am not stringing together a long dynamic path.

**Here is the file structure:**

```
-components folder
|-GameLogic.js (parent element that handles the render)
|-Bandersnatch.js (child element)
|-NewComponents folder
  |-ImageContainer.js (grandChild element)
  |-ImageSquare.js (great grandChild element)
-images folder
  |-snatch_images folder (yes... I know how bad this sounds...)
    |-escape_snatch.png
    |-The rest of the images (there are about 20)
 -characters.json
 -App.js
```

**JSON example: I need the file path at Array[0].scene[0].choiceOneImg**

```
[

{
    "name": "Giraffe",
    "alive": true,
    "active": true,
    "staticImg": "images/characters/static/static_giraffe.png",
    "animatedImg": "images/characters/animated/animated_giraffe.png",
    "cagedImg": "images/characters/caged/caged_giraffe.png",
    "scene": [
        {
            "used": false,
            "backgroundImg": "images/BG_images/zooBG.png",
            "question": "........." ,
            "answerTrue": ".......",
            "answerFalse": ".......",
            "choiceOne": "RUN FOR IT!",
            "choiceTwo": "Stay loyal",
            "choiceOneImg": "../images/snatch_images/escape_snatch.png",
            "choiceTwoImg": "images/snatch_images/stay_snatch.png",
            "incorrectResult": 0,
            "correctAnswer": "choiceOne",
            "correct": true
        },
```

**Here is the Parent, GameLogic.js that passes the currentCharacter, sceneLocation from the state that is constantly changing:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Snatch from "./Bandersnatch";
import characters from "../characters.json";

class GameLogic extends Component {

state ={
    unlockedCharacters : 0,
    currentCharacter : 0,
    sceneLocation : 0,
    points : 0,
    showCaracterSelect: true,
    showMessage: false,
    showSnatch: false,
    showCanvas: false,

}

componentDidMount() {

}


render() {
    return (
        <Snatch 
            sceneLocation = {this.state.sceneLocation}
            currentCharacter = {this.state.currentCharacter}
            choiceOneAlt = "ChoiceOne"
            choiceOneImg = {characters[this.state.currentCharacter].scene[this.state.sceneLocation].choiceOneImg}
            choiceTwoAlt = "ChoiceTwo"
            choiceTwoImg = {characters[this.state.currentCharacter].scene[this.state.sceneLocation].choiceTwoImg}
        />
    )
}
}

 export default GameLogic;
```

**Then this is passed to the child component, Bandersnatch.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import characters from "../characters.json";
import { HeaderH2, ImageContainer, ImageSquare, ImageText, ProgressBar, Timer } from "./NewComponents/AllComponents";

const Snatch = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <title>Decision Time</title>
            <div className="w3-container">
                <div className="container">
                    <HeaderH2 text="What Would You Like To Do?" />

                    <div className="row">
                        <ImageContainer
                            sceneLocation = {props.sceneLocation}
                            currentCharacter = {props.currentCharacter}
                            choiceOneAlt = {props.choiceOneAlt}
                            choiceOneImg = {props.choiceOneImg}
                            choiceTwoAlt = {props.choiceTwoAlt}
                            choiceTwoImg = {props.choiceTwoImg}
                        />
                        {/* <ProgressBar /> */}
                        {/* <ImageText 
                            sceneLocation = {props.sceneLocation}
                            currentCharacter = {props.currentCharacter}
                        /> */}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );

 }

 export default Snatch;
```

**Which is then passed to ImageContainer:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ImageSquare from "./ImageSquare";
import characterObject from "../../characters.json";

const ImageContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-md-6 optionOneclassName">
                <ImageSquare
                    imgsrc={props.choiceOneImg}
                    altText={props.choiceOneAlt}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 optionTwoclassName">
                <ImageSquare
                    imgsrc={props.choiceTwoImg}
                    altText={props.choiceTwoAlt}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    )
 };

 export default ImageContainer;
```

**And then finally accepted in the ImageSquare.js:**

```
import React from "react";

const ImageSquare = (props) => { // passing in the img src
 return (

    <img src={props.imgsrc} alt={props.altText} height="600" width="600" />
   )
};

export default ImageSquare;
```

Thank you so much for your help! I am not sure if it is easier, [but the repo is here](http://git@github.com:mggude/zoosnatch2.git)

Answer (score 0):

Use require to load the image. Passing path to img directly won’t work. Either you need import or require to load the image

You need to add ../ before path

Change

```
   import React from "react";
   const ImageSquare = (props) => { // passing in the img src
     return (
         <img src={props.imgsrc} alt={props.altText} height="600" width="600" />
     )
  };

 export default ImageSquare;
```

To

```
    import React from "react";
    const ImageSquare = (props) => { // passing in the img src
     const path = "../"+props.imgsrc;
      return (
        <img src={require(path)} alt={props.altText} height="600" width="600" />
       )
 };

  export default ImageSquare;
```

Comment: So this change is in the great grandchild component (ImageSquare.js) it looks like. When creating the image path from the JSON object, which file is actually rendering it, APP.js, the Parent, Child, GrandChild or Great GrandChild? I tried it with:
"choiceOneImg": "../../images/snatch_images/escape_snatch.png",
"choiceOneImg": "../images/snatch_images/escape_snatch.png",
and "choiceOneImg": "./images/snatch_images/escape_snatch.png",

The errors say it can not find the Module followed by the path options.

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason it still is not working correctly. Even with starting at just "images/snatch_images/escape_snatch.png", then going up 1 level, 2 levels, and then 3 levels (just to be extra crazy). I have been running into this same issue... I am not sure if maybe I am just WAY off on my file structure?